# Index problem in mutableListOf with LiveData and ViewModel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm

I'm getting the data from Firebase using ViewModel and when I try to bind the data with the textView I see the next error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.pruebafirebase/com.example.pruebafirebase.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by lazy {ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)}
    private var dataList = mutableListOf<User>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel.fetchUserData().observe(this, Observer {it: MutableList<User>!
            dataList = it
        })

        bindView(dataList[0])
    }


    fun bindView(users: User) {
        nameOne.text = users.name
        lastOne.text = users.last
    }

}
```

Comment: Move `bindView(dataList[0])` inside your observer function. Otherwise you are trying to retrieve the value before anything has been added to the list.

Comment: Perfect, I've been more than an hour trying to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `observer` is an async operation, so that can happen after the line `bindView` is executed.

```
viewModel.fetchUserData().observe(this, Observer {it: MutableList<User>!
    bindView(dataList[0])
})
```

The lines of code are written in a linear manner, but the code execution is not linear, by the time the previous `bindView(dataList[0])` was executed the above `observer` was set but the `dataList = it` could have happened or not, most likely no.